# intermittent error from imu sensor

Tags: imu, rviz, transform, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In RVIZ, I am getting some intermittent errors, that are hardly visible on the status screen.
It gives this 1 out of each lets say 1000 messages.

It says:

```
no transform for fixed frame map. tf error: [lookup would require extrapolation into future.
```

why does this error message happen? and what can i do to fix it.

Best regards,
Can

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335688/intermittent-error-from-imu-sensor/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2019-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its an issue with your TF configuration, either its not being published fast enough, or the timeout period on those transforms are too low.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on 2019-10-19**:
Hello,
How are the timeout periods for the transforms determined? I changed the frequency of transforms from 10hz to 100hz (by changing the 100ms at the end to 10ms) and it seems it solved the problem, but I have this question: lets say I have a sensor publishing with base_imu_link as frame_id, and then I have tf broadcasting from /base_imu_link to /base_footprint. if my imu sensor is outputting at 200hz, what frequency should i publish the transform for /base_imu_link to /base_footprint?
best regards,
C.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-10-21**:
I'd have to know alot more and in detail about your setup to fully answer. However 100hz is reasonable so if your problem is solved, I'd just leave it at that or I'd need to see alot into your stack